# jQuery OpenID: .submit is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am using the Open-Id selector jQuery plugin for my site. Though, I have set it up correctly the images are showing up but it does'nt seem to work. I click images and I get `$("#openid_form").submit` is not a function.

I did `console.log($("#openid_form"))+Firebug` and `.submit` is not a function in the list, [its submit.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuwVq.png). I checked many times but submit.php is not written anywhere. I can't seem to trace the reason for this error.

**Update**:A "view selection source" of form shows the following generated HTML:

```
<form action="/kohana/signup" method="post" id="openid_form" accept-charset="utf-8">        ....
     <div id="openid_btns"><div id="openid_highlight">
     <a title="Log in with Google" href="javascript:openid.signin('google');" style="background: url(&quot;/kohana/media/images/openid-providers-en.png&quot;) repeat scroll 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="google openid_large_btn"></a></div>.......</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: @undefined: Its a one liner : `openid.init('openid_identifier');` in `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was an obsolete version of jQuery. I was using obsolete version `1.2.6` bundled with plugin.